# Dados sendo multiplicado na tabela

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Eu tenho um cadastro de receitas e nesse cadastro tem um botão que clona os campos "quantidade de ingredientes" e o "combo box do ingredientes". Se eu adiciono somente uma quantidade e ingrediente, o cadastro é salvo corretamente.Porém o mesmo não acontece com  2 ou mais ingredientes. Alguma sugestão?

Inputs:

```
<div id= "clonardiv">
    <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="idMedida">Quantidade:</label>  
<div class="col-md-5">
<input id="idMedida" name="idMedida[]" type="text" placeholder="Insira aqui a quantidade de ingredientes necessários" class="form-control input-md" required="">
 </div>
</div>

    <div class= "form-group">
        <label for="ingredientes" class="col-md-4 control-label">Escolha os ingredientes</label>
        <select name="ingredientes[]" id="ingredientes" class="col-md-4 control-label" required="1">
            <option>Selecione...</option>
            <?php
            while($dados3 = mysql_fetch_array($q1)) {   
            ?>
            <option value="<?= $dados3['id_ingredientes'] ?>">
                <?= $dados3['nome'] ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div id= "clonar" ></div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="clonar()"; class="btn btn-outlined btn-success" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
```

PHP:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$titulo= $_POST["idTituloReceita"];
$imagem= $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
$culinaria= $_POST["culinaria"];
$tempopreparo= $_POST["idTempopreparo"];
$porcao=$_POST["idServePorcao"];
session_start();
$emailr = $_SESSION['emailLogin'];
$descricao =$_POST["idPreparo"]; 
$video = $_POST["idVideo"];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw", "culinaria");

foreach($_POST["idMedida"] as $medida) {

foreach ($_POST["ingredientes"] as $ingredientes){

$sql="INSERT INTO receitas(email,id_tipoculinaria,serve_porcao,tempo_preparo,titulo ,imagem ,video) 
VALUES ('$emailr','$culinaria','$porcao','$tempopreparo','$titulo','$imagem','$video')";

$query = $con->query($sql) or die( mysqli_error( $con ) );

$id= $con->insert_id;

//echo "$id";

$sql="INSERT INTO ingredientes_da_receita(id_receitas, id_ingredientes, quantidade, descricao) 
VALUES ('$id' ,".$ingredientes.",".$medida.",'$descricao')";

$query = $con->query($sql) or die( mysqli_error( $con ) );

echo "<script>alert('Receita Cadastrada com sucesso');window.location='cadastroreceita.php' </script>"; 
}
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

controleclone.js:

```
function clonar() {
    var destino = document.getElementById("clonar");
    var novadiv = document.createElement("div");
    var conteudo = document.getElementById("clonardiv");
    novadiv.innerHTML = conteudo.innerHTML;
    destino.appendChild(novadiv);
}
```

Comment: pode postar essa função clonar()?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo claro, esta no corpo da pergunta.

Comment: rapaz tenho q sair agora mas no seu select está faltando  multiple veja esse tutorial   http://www.criarweb.com/artigos/180.php

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo vou ver, muito obrigado

Comment: percebi o que faz a função clonar, então o multiple no select não tem nada a ver

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo alguma outra dica?

Comment: Algumas coisas não entendi. Porque um foreach na tabela receitas? Nessa tabela existe um campo auto incremento?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Cara, era esse o problema não duplicou mais mas o problema agora esta na quantidade,ele não atualiza corretamente.
Exemplo: 300 g de arroz e 500 g de carne.
Na tabela fica algo assim: 300 g de arroz e de carne. O que poderia ser?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60682/discussion-between-leo-caracciolo-and-malfus).

Comment: entra ai no chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é necessário dois foreach.

Use  [**array_combine**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-combine.php) para combinar os dois arrays  `$idMedida`  `$ingredientes`  e fazer um foreach para inserir no banco as chaves e valores do array resultante

```
$titulo= $_POST["idTituloReceita"]; 
$imagem= $_FILES['imagem']['name']; 
$culinaria= $_POST["culinaria"]; 
$tempopreparo= $_POST["idTempopreparo"]; 
$porcao=$_POST["idServePorcao"]; 
session_start(); 
$emailr = $_SESSION['emailLogin']; 
$descricao =$_POST["idPreparo"]; 
$video = $_POST["idVideo"]; 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw", "culinaria"); 

$sql="INSERT INTO receitas(email,id_tipoculinaria,serve_porcao,tempo_preparo,titulo ,imagem ,video) 
VALUES ('$emailr','$culinaria','$porcao','$tempopreparo','$titulo','$imagem','$video')"; 

$query = $con->query($sql) or die( mysqli_error( $con ) ); 

$idMedida=$_POST["idMedida"]; 
$ingredientes = $_POST["ingredientes"]; 

$combArray=array_combine($ingredientes,$idMedida); 

$id= $con->insert_id; 

foreach($combArray as $key => $value) 
{ 
   $sql2="INSERT INTO ingredientes_da_receita(id_receitas, id_ingredientes, quantidade, descricao) VALUES ('$id','$key','$value','$descricao')"; 
   $query = $con->query($sql2) or die( mysqli_error( $con ) ); 
} 

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo!!!!